Can I burn Solana dApp Store publish NFT?
I'm currently working on a Solana dApp and published many versions of it to dApp Store.
It costed me a lot of SOL (Around 8 SOL for the last 2 years), now SOL price is also so expensive (>200$). So I'm making this thread to ask:

Is is safe If I burn some of old publishing NFT and metadata NFT and take back some SOL?
Is there anyway to do it easily?

